# Is there such thing as not less than?

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

In my code, I'm trying to make a not less than operator. I can't do `a !< b`... what can I do? Is there any package / method I can use?

Comment: How about the `>=` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I am so stupid! I could just do `a >= b`!

Comment: All hail the lord Doge!

Answer (score 8):

The opposite of `a < b` is `a >= b`, not `a > b`.

EDIT: The syntax you were looking for is `!(a < b)`

Comment: Nice! It works, but I prefer `<=`